Understanding convergence of solutions obtained with Frobenius Theorem
I know how to solve ODEs of the form:
$$y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0$$
in singular regular points using Frobenius Theorem, and said theorem also provides some constraints as to where the functions involved are convergent. Nonetheless, I can't seem to find the convergence radius of the solution itself.
Say $y_1(x)$ is one of the two independent solutions to the equation. Then, I know it will take the form:
$$y_1(x)=u_1(x)|x|^{r_1}$$
where $u_1(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ and $r_1$ is the greatest of the two roots of the indical polynomial. I know if the convergence radius of $p$ is $R_p$ and that of $q$ is $R_q$, then the convergence radius of $u_q(x)$, $R_u$, will be equal or greater than the minimum of the other two radii:
$$R_u \geq min\lbrace R_p, R_q\rbrace$$
Nonetheless, this doesn't tell me much about the convergence radius of my actual solution, $y_q(x)$. Is there a way to know said radius?
